# Can't iterate through 2 levels of categories

Tags: categories

I purchased a Wordpress theme, for a restaurant.

The theme uses Posts for each (food)menu entry, and Categories to segment the menu into sections.

The theme is built for 1 level hierarchies. e.g:

```
>Menu
>>>Breakfast
>>>Lunch
>>>Dinner
```

However, the restaurant I am working for has a more complex menu:

```
>Menu
>>>Breakfast
>>>>>>Food
>>>>>>Sides
>>>>>>Drinks
>>>Lunch
>>>>>>Small
>>>>>>Large
>>>>>>Sides
```

Here is the [original index.php](http://pastebin.com/mzsHAQXC)

Here is my [modified index.php](http://pastebin.com/HGiEth5E), which attempts to iterate first within the 1st level of categories (e.g. Breakfast, Lunch...), and then through all 2nd level categories (e.g. Breakfast > Food, Breakfast > Sides...).

In both, $menuCat refers to the "Menu" parent category.

[This](http://www.bibandtucker.net.au/test/) is the live site, using a child theme, and the new index.php.  It manages to find the "Lunch" category, but not the "Breakfast" category, and it doesn't output the subcategories.

I receive a PHP exception:

> Warning: Illegal offset type in isset or empty in
>   /.../wp-includes/taxonomy.php on line 1236

Here is taxonomy.php from line 1234:

```
if ( $parent ) {
    $hierarchy = _get_term_hierarchy($taxonomies[0]);
    if ( !isset($hierarchy[$parent]) )
        return $empty_array;
}
```

So, it seems the $hierarchy of the parent is not not set.  I don't know what this means.

Answer (score 1):

on line 59, `parent` is expected to be an integer, you're passing an object:

```
$args = array(
    'orderby' => 'slug',
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'parent' => $category // <---- here
);
```

it should be `$category->term_id`

Comment: Thanks Milo!  It's now working, except it is only displaying the "Lunch" category, and not the "Breakfast, Dinner or Dessert" categories.